# IdentityModel.OidcClient for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, openid, openid-connect

Anybody know if there is a library to connect to OpenID from a application Winforms VB.NET ?

I found exactly a library for my purpose IdentityModel.OidcClient but it's in .NET C#. I need a framework like that but in VB

Thanks you so much for any suggestion.

Comment: You can use C# libraries in your vb.net projects